# Remove rows with at least 1 value less than a certain limit in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix, and I want to remove all rows that contain at least one element less than a value, 3 on this example. Sample data:

```
A=matrix(c(10,2,4,8,5,4,8,10,5),byrow=T,ncol=3)

#Remove rows that contain at least one value less than 3

final_matrix=matrix(c(8,5,4,8,10,5), byrow=T,ncol=3)
```

How to get to the final matrix from the initial matrix A? My real matrix contains thousands of rows tens of columns, this is a toy example. I tried `A=A[A>3,]` but I get an error `"logical subscript too long"`

Comment: `A[rowSums(A < 3) == 0, ]`

Comment: I didn't know this use of rowSums,  I thought it was only for sums, thank you so much Ronak